# Mutiple maps followed by one reduce with Hadoop and HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have several Hbase tables.  I wish to run a map task on each table (each map being a different `Mapper` class since each table contains heterogeneous data) followed by one reduce.

I cannot work out if this is possible without explictly reducing the data after each map into an interim `SequenceFile`.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can only run an MR on one table at a time (see [TableMapReduceUtil](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.html)). So most probably, your best bet is as you suspected: save the output of each table into an interim location (e.g. SequenceFile or a tmp hbase table) and then write a final MR job that takes that location as an input and merges the results. Also, if each MR job outputs data in a common format, you may not even need the last MR merge job.

Comment: Looks like you are correct.  I notice there is a Jira Issue open for it. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-2965